# Attempting to parse a file (mmp format) from legacy software using Python

Tags: java, python-3.x, binary, chunks

I have a piece of Legacy software called Mixmeister that saved off playlist files in an MMP format.

This format appears to contain binary as well as file paths.

I am looking to extract the file paths along with any additional information I can from these files.

I see this has been done using JAVA (I do not know JAVA) here (see aorund ln 56):
https://github.com/liesen/CueMeister/blob/master/src/mixmeister/mmp/MixmeisterPlaylist.java

and Haskell here:
https://github.com/larjo/MixView/blob/master/ListFiles.hs

So far,  I have tried reading the file as binary (got stuck); using Regex expressions (messy output with moderate success) and attempting to try some code to read chunks (beyond my skill level).

The code I am using with moderate success for Regex is:

```
file='C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\mixmeisterfile.mmp'
with open(file, 'r', encoding="Latin-1") as filehandle:
#with open(file, 'rb') as filehandle:    
    for text in filehandle:
        b = re.search('TRKF(.*)TKLYTRKM', text)
        if b:
            print(b.group())
```

Again, this gets me close but is messy (the data is not all intact and surrounded by ascii and binary characters).  Basically, my logic is just searching between two strings to attempt to extract the filenames.  What I am really trying to do is get closer to something like what the JAVA  has in GIT, which is (the code below is sampled from the GIT link):

```
    List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    Marker trks = null;

    for (Chunk chunk : trkl.getChunks()) {
      TrackHeader header = new TrackHeader();
      String file = "";
      List<Marker> meta = new LinkedList<Marker>();

      if (chunk.canContainSubchunks()) {
        for (Chunk chunk2 : ((ChunkContainer) chunk).getChunks()) {
          if ("TRKH".equals(chunk2.getIdentifier())) {
            header = readTrackHeader(chunk2);
          } else if ("TRKF".equals(chunk2.getIdentifier())) {
            file = readTrackFile(chunk2);
          } else {
            if (chunk2.canContainSubchunks()) {
              for (Chunk chunk3 : ((ChunkContainer) chunk2).getChunks()) {
                if ("TRKM".equals(chunk3.getIdentifier())) {
                  meta.add(readTrackMarker(chunk3));
                } else if ("TRKS".equals(chunk3.getIdentifier())) {
                  trks = readTrackMarker(chunk3);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Track tr = new Track(header, file, meta);
```

I am guessing this would either use RIFF or the chunk library in Python if not done using a Regex?  Although I read the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/chunk.html, I am not sure that I understand how to go about something like this - mainly I do not understand how to properly read the binary file which has the visible mixed in file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's going on here but I'll try my best and if it doesn't work out then please excuse my stupidity. When I had a project for parsing weather data for a Metar, I realized that my main issue was that I was trying to turn everything into a String type, which wasn't suitable for all the data and so it would just come out as nothing. Your for loop should work just fine. However, when you traverse, have you tried making everything the same type, such as a Character/String type? Perhaps there are certain elements messed up simply because they don't match the type you are going for.